# How do I change the url back to mysite.com in django after loging in the user?

Tags: python, django

I have two apps in my django project. After loging the user in through "visit" app I redirect to "mainapp". However, my url patter becomes something like this : `mysite/accounts/profile/`

If I try specifying in `urls.py` I get redirected to "visit" app. How do I reset my url

**visit/views.py**

```
def profile(request):
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("main:home"))
```

**main/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'accounts/profile', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

**main/views.py**

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'main/home.html')
```

Comment: after visit you are redirecting to namespace:home which is account.profile (its correct ) if you want to reset url just use return redirect('/') and check the behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You could try specifying redirect url in your `settings.py` file. Just include `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = /mainapp/accounts/profile/` in that file and it should work. `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL` is also something you can list in your settings file to specify where to redirect after user logout.